# How to prevent user from entering invalid values in wxGrid cell?

Tags: c++, events, wxwidgets

I'd like to create wxGrid where user can edit some cells, but prohibit entering incorrect valued. For example, only strings of length 4 could be entered there. So, if user enter string of another length, I'd like to show a error message and return to cell editor. How to do it?

If I handle a cell change event EVT_GRID_CELL_CHANGE, for example

```
void Frame::OnGridCellChange(wxGridEvent& event)
{
    int r = event.GetRow(); // get changed cell
    int c = event.GetCol(); // get changed cell

    if (Grid->GetCellValue(r, c).length() != 4)
       {Error E (this);
          /* Create the Error message */
        E.ShowModal();
          // The error message shown, uses clicks OK

        // So, what to do here? 


}
```

`Grid->ShowCellEditControl();` is not a solution because cell change won't be generated if user edit nothing, but just click another cell - incorrect value would appear in Grid.

Handling `EVT_GRID_EDITOR_HIDDEN` seems not suitable since it appears before new value actually saved to cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use your own specialization of the cell editor.

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_grid_cell_editor.html

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using an event of type `wxEVT_GRID_CELL_CHANGING` would work for you? If the string that is returned by calling [GetString()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_command_event.html#a24323d78936e5f6cd7f4780371f373e0) on the event is not four characters long then you can veto the event, something like:

```
void Frame::OnGridCellChanging(wxGridEvent& event)
{
    if (event.GetString().length() != 4)
    {
        //Veto the event so the change is not stored
        event.Veto();

        Error E (this);
        E.ShowModal();
}
```

This does seem to require a wxWidgets 2.9.x release however.

Comment: thanks for advising, well, I'm not ready to use 2.9.x version yet, but anyway, it would be better to preserve user-entered data, but prohibit applying cell edits, while this way it seems like entered data will be lost...

Comment: You have the old and new strings though, so preserving the data shouldn't be a problem. I suspect writing your own wxGridCellEditor derived from wxGridCellTextEditor might be the easiest way as that way you can perform validation before the editor closes, and so no data is lost but the string doesn't get written.

Comment: Thanks, this is more straight forward and worked for me.